# Linking two libraries together with CMake

Tags: c++, cmake

File Structure:

```
CMakeLists.txt
src/
    evolution.cpp
    evolution.h
    main.cpp
    helpers/
        disposable.h
    engine/
        game.h
        game.cpp
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(evolution)

add_library(helpers
    src/helpers/disposable.h)
set_target_properties(helpers PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX)

add_library(engine
    src/engine/game.h
    src/engine/game.cpp)

add_executable(evolution src/main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(evolution engine helpers)
```

The `Game` class (`game.h`) inherits from `Diposable` (`disposable.h`), but I am unable to build the project with a simple `#include "disposable.h"` in the `game.h` file.

How do I configure CMake so that the `engine` library can see the `helpers` library?

CMake error:

```
[ 20%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/engine.dir/src/engine/game.cpp.o
In file included from /home/shane/projects/evolution/src/engine/game.cpp:1:
/home/shane/projects/evolution/src/engine/game.h:4:10: fatal error: disposable.h: No such file or directory
    4 | #include "disposable.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Comment: `#include "../helpers/disposable.h"` or add the helpers folder as an [include directory](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/command/target_include_directories.html) to the `engine` target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding headers to a project really only helps IDEs find the headers.  It doesn't change the build instructions.  Instead you need to use `target_include_directories()` with a `INTERFACE` or `PUBLIC` section to get any libraries that link to this to add the include directories to itself.

Your helpers library is more of an interface for now.  To get this minimum example working do this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(evolution)

add_library(helpers INTERFACE) # INTERFACE is good for header-only libraries
target_include_directories(helpers INTERFACE src/helpers) 

add_library(engine
    src/engine/game.h
    src/engine/game.cpp)

add_executable(evolution src/main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(evolution engine helpers)
```

Now include with angular brackets: `#include <disposable.h>`

If your library becomes more complicated (more than just header files), then replace `INTERFACE` in `add_library` with your sources. To make include directories available to the `helpers` library and any library that links to it, change `INTERFACE` to `PUBLIC` in `target_include_directories`.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(evolution)

add_library(helpers src/helpers/helper.cpp)
target_include_directories(helpers PUBLIC src/helpers)

add_library(engine
    src/engine/game.h
    src/engine/game.cpp)

add_executable(evolution src/main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(evolution engine helpers)
```